# python multiple inheritance: avoid calling the constructors twice in diamond shape

Tags: python, initialization, multiple-inheritance, super, diamond-problem

Consider the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__")
        super(A, self).__init__()          # 1
        print("A.__init__ finished")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__")
        super(B, self).__init__()          # 2
        print("B.__init__ finished")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C.__init__")
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print("C.__init__ finished")

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("D.__init__")
        print("Initializing B")
        B.__init__(self)                   # 3
        print("B initialized")
        print("Initializing C")
        C.__init__(self)                   # 4
        print("C initialized")
        print("D.__init__ finished")

D()

# D.__init__
# Initializing B
# B.__init__
# C.__init__
# A.__init__
# A.__init__ finished
# C.__init__ finished
# B.__init__ finished
# B initialized
# Initializing C
# C.__init__
# A.__init__
# A.__init__ finished
# C.__init__ finished
# C initialized
# D.__init__ finished
```

As far as I understand, the algorithm is as follows:

```
D.__init__ at (3) -> B.__init__ -> 
-> super().__init__ -> (super of self.__class__).__init__ ->
-> C.__init__ (# why C?) -> super().__init__ -> 
-> A.__init__

D.__init__ at (4) -> C.__init__ ->
-> super().__init__ -> 
-> A.__init__
```

Actually there are three questions:
1. Why `super().__init__()` call in `B.__init__` (at 2) calls `C.__init__` when `self` is an instance of `D`?
2. How to avoid calling `C.__init__` and `A.__init__` twice in this case?
2.1 What is the right way to initialize all the classes the current class inherits from?

Answer (score 5):

Q: *Why `super().__init__()` call in `B.__init__` (at 2) calls `C.__init__` when self is an instance of D?*

When you call

```
super(X, self).__init__
```

Python looks up [the MRO](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#method-resolution-order) `self.__class__.mro()`. It then calls `__init__` from the *next* class in the MRO after X.

When self is an instance of `D`, `self.__class__.mro()` is `[D, B, C, A]`. So `super(B, self).__init__()` calls `C.__init__(self)`.

---

Q: *What is the right way to initialize all the classes the current class inherits from?*

Use super in `D.__init__` as well:

```
class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("D.__init__")
        super(D, self).__init__()
        print("D.__init__ finished")
```

Comment: I posted a simplified case. Actual classes B and C have different signature.

Comment: The is one of the [pitfalls](https://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) of using super. The signatures must all match, because you can not control which classes's method is called next by super. As a counterbalance to the pitfalls article, also read [Hettinger's  take on super()](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).