# Multiple inheritance method resolving: C++ vs Python

Tags: python, c++, multiple-inheritance

I'm seeing very different behavior in how C++ and Python handle the diamond inheritance scenario.

For the following two code snippets, the logic is the same but the output is different. I don't understand why. I'd really appreciate it if someone could offer some insight.

Python prints out "B B"

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'A'

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B'
    def bar(self):
        self.foo()

class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print 'C'
    def bar(self):
        self.foo()

class D(B, C):
    def bar(self):
        B.bar(self)
        C.bar(self)

D().bar()
```

But C++ prints out "B C"

```
struct A
{   
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }   
};  

struct B : public A
{   
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }   

    virtual void bar() { this->foo(); }
};  

struct C : public A
{   
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }   

    virtual void bar() { this->foo(); }
};  

struct D : public B, public C
{   
    virtual void bar() {
        B::bar();
        C::bar();
    }   
};  

int main()
{   
    D().bar();
}
```

When I add the line `cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl;` to every `bar()` method above in C++, this is what gets printed out:

```
B 0x7fff803d9b70
C 0x7fff803d9b78
D 0x7fff803d9b70
```

It seems that `B` and `D` share the same address, but `C` is in a different vtable.

**Edit**

As suggested in the reply @JoranBeasley, I tried the following checks for the python code:

```
D.foo == B.foo
D.foo == C.foo
D.foo is B.foo
D.foo is C.foo
```

Python 2.7 prints out `True False False False`

Python 3.4 prints out `True False True False`

It seems that both `B.foo` and `D.foo` are the same method by value in both python 2 and 3, but python 2 makes a copy while python 3 doesn't.

Comment: If you want python-like inheritance in C++, you need to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: This C++ is not a real diamond: `D` has 2 different inherited `A` bases.

Comment: @o11c: I actually want the other way around: C++ behavior is preferred.

Comment: It is a good question. You can read a few points from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457603/python-multiple-inheritance-avoid-calling-the-constructors-twice-in-diamond-sha

Comment: @BhargavRao that's a really good post. Thx!

Comment: @JimJarvis That is not truly possible in Python unless you use metaclass hackery to generate copies of base classes, which will likely confuse *everyone* and break all sorts of things.

Comment: good question. I would have expected B,C as in C++. Good to learn these things about python, and thanks to @Joran Beasley's answer

Answer (score 4):

I can only explain the python bits ...

`C.bar(self)`

passes the instance of D that you created in as `self`

so when it calls `self.foo()` it is no different than if you had said `self.foo()` inside of `D.bar` (i.e `self` remains staticly the same thing)

since inheritance is done Right to Left `B.foo` shadows `C.foo`

```
D.foo is B.foo # should print True
D.foo is C.foo # should print false
```

you could of coarse always call

```
C.foo(self) #prints C as expected
```

this really has nothing to do with Python multiple inheritance method resolution order since that is handled with the `super()` call ... instead you are trying to explicitly call your parent class methods, rather than allowing python to resolve them for you implicitly

as far as why its different than C++ , its because it is two seperate languages that implemented inheritance and multiple inheritance in distinct ways...

as mentioned in the comments you could change D's definition to

```
class D(C,B):
     ...
```

then `D().foo()` will print `C`

Comment: Also mention that if he changes the order of inheritance (`class D(B, C):`) to (`class D(C, B):`) it will print `C C` ;) (after you have explained right-to-left inheritance)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But both lines print out `False`.

Comment: @JimJarvis Could you please mention the Python version?

Comment: @BhargavRao python 2.7

Comment: @JimJarvis Aha. That is the reason. Joran's answer is in Python3.

Comment: hmmm you are right ... I will look into that when I get home (Im actually on 2.6.6) thats what I get for not testing it ... i will figure it out

Comment: im sure its something about inheriting for `object` in python3 it is automagic ... in python2 it has to be explicit

Comment: well now im really confused and starting to doubt myself and my understanding ... I cant get them to evaluate to the same no matter what in python2 ... oh well Im still sure that this is how it works :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: python 3's behavior makes more sense. B.foo should be the same as D.foo

Comment: @JimJarvis Want to see more fun. Remove the `foo` function completely from class `B` and remove the inheritance of `object` from `A`. Then execute the code. It will yield more surprising results.

Comment: @BhargavRao it prints out "A A" ... and python 3 prints out "C C". I've heard about this python object mechanism change, but never see it in action.